# Factory Design pattern do-nots?

Tags: factory, factory-pattern

Whenever I see factory design pattern, it always has a simple `new FactoryName.build()` approach. And when creating objects, they have dependencies, but in my case I have an existing projects where I am operating more so in the run-time than at the initialization time (think inside of an existing, intricate code base, as opposed to a simple factory design example). So in order to inject needed dependencies, it is not possible for my implementation of `build` to just be implemented as `return new Blah(new This(), new That())`.

So what if I want to pass parameters to build (eg: `build(SomeENUM type)`, and/or even auto-detect dependencies inside build (eg: `some logic to auto-detect SomeENUM type`). Is either or both of those inherently wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The "create" patterns like (factory/build) abstract the
object instantiation process by **hiding** how the objects are created and make the system independent of the object creation process.

If I understand you question right , you can't "play" with `SomeENUM type` inside *build factory* process. This is a main goal of Factory patterns to make all process like *black box*

I took print screens from good doc.:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Okay, so the caller to a factory should declare up front what type of implementation it wants. Metaphorically, it should order off of a restaurant menu, and not ask the waiter what is good to eat?

Comment: right, but if you use Abstract Factory Pattern you can decide in which restaurant to go (to change menu). See example above. BTW, Build Factory is based on which parameters you passed to Factory initiation. And on other side of door you get the product.